# Getting the same error when trying to run my application. "TypeError: this.microservicesModule.register is not a function"

Tags: node.js, angular, api, npm, nestjs

Every time I try to run my application I've being getting the same error:

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.microservicesModule.register is not a function
>       at NestApplication.registerModules (C:\Users\\Documents\AWD\ClientPortalAPI\node_modules@nestjs\core\nest-application.js:86:38)
>       at NestApplication.init"...

The application seems to run on other computers, I tried downloading it from the repo again, reinstalling all the npm packages, globally and locally, installing all the missing dependencies from @nestjs individually, still I always get the same error. Any idea of what could it be?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Installing the following two dependencies worked:

`npm i -S @nestjs/websockets`
`npm i -S @nestjs/microservices`